# How do I write this particular method for the print function in R?

Tags: r, function

Specifically, I am trying to write a method for the print function that will input a dataset with the class dataWithMetadata, will output the metadata attribute directly to the console as a message, and return as well as print the original dataset as a dataframe.

I have already tried this code in order to do this

```
print.dataWithMetadata <- function(x) {
  cat("Metadata:\n")
  print(x$metadata)
  cat("\nOriginal dataset:\n")
  df <- as.data.frame(x$data)
  print(df)
  return(df)
}
print.dataWithMetadata(myDataset)
```

Additionally, before attempting to create this function, I set the metadata of the dataset I am using as an attribute of myDataset and I changed its class so it has the classes "dataWithMetadata" and "data.frame". I used this code to do this:

```
attr(myActualData, "metadata") <- myAssignment6Metadata
class(myActualData) <- c("dataWithMetadata", "data.frame")
```

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you call `print` in a `print` method you will start an infinite recursion. Call `NextMethod` instead.

Now that you have a `print` method for objects of class `"dataWithMetadata"`, you don't need to call

```
print.dataWithMetadata(x)
```

just

```
print(x)
```

will do.

Also, I have defined functions `as_dataWithMetadata` and `is_dataWithMetadata` to make creation and testing of your objects easier.

```r
print.dataWithMetadata <- function(x) {
  metadata <- attr(x, "metadata")
  cat("Metadata:\n")
  print(metadata)
  cat("\nOriginal dataset:\n")
  NextMethod(x)
  invisible(x)
}

as_dataWithMetadata <- function(x, metadata) {
  old_class <- class(x)
  attr(x, "metadata") <- metadata
  class(x) <- c("dataWithMetadata", old_class)
  x
}
is_dataWithMetadata <- function(x) inherits(x, "dataWithMetadata")
                                
myAssignment6Metadata <- "metadata attribute"
myDataset <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = letters[1:5])
myDataset <- as_dataWithMetadata(myDataset, myAssignment6Metadata)
class(myDataset)
#> [1] "dataWithMetadata" "data.frame"

is_dataWithMetadata(myDataset)
#> [1] TRUE

print(myDataset)
#> Metadata:
#> [1] "metadata attribute"
#> 
#> Original dataset:
#>   x y
#> 1 1 a
#> 2 2 b
#> 3 3 c
#> 4 4 d
#> 5 5 e
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>